# Google map for reviewed places

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to visualize on a Google map all places I've given a review on Google?  Something similar to My Maps, but with places I reviewed automatically added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that since a few weeks it's possible.

Click on any place you've ever reviewed, then click on "Reviews", find your review and click on your profile icon. You'll be brought to a map containing your reviewed places, marked with this icon:

[image]

The map also contains all your Saved Places.

Note: this map only shows the most recently reviewed places. I don't know if it's because the Review Map is a new feature and just started tracking your reviews, or it does this by design.